# BindingAdapter has lost binding with unknown reason

Tags: android, data-binding, kotlin, android-viewmodel

The binding adapter has lost binding to the view model. However I have no idea what is the reason. The SpinnerTextView in the code is a textview popping an alert dialog for selecting value from a list. Setting the title will set The textview's text as the String value. The binding lost cause the textview does not show the new value, is there any solution?

I have put some breakpoints, and I found that the pickedQuantity = "0" worked and also pickedQuantity.value = quantities.value!![index] has been run too. However, in the BindingAdapter.kt only pickedQuantity = "0" triggered the setTitle function.
Therefore, my TextView will always shows 0 but not changing when I select value.

BindingAdapter.kt

```
@BindingAdapter("spinnerTitle")
fun<T> SpinnerTextView<T>.setTitle(str: String) {
    title = str
}

@BindingAdapter("spinnerAlertTitle")
fun<T> SpinnerTextView<T>.setAlertTitle(str: String) {
    alertTitle = str
}

@BindingAdapter("spinnerItems")
fun<T> SpinnerTextView<T>.setItems(list: List<T>) {
    items = list
}

@BindingAdapter("spinnerItemHandler")
fun<T> SpinnerTextView<T>.setHandler(handler: (Int) -> Unit) {
    valueChanged = handler
}
```

TicketTypeViewModel.kt

```
class TicketTypeViewModel : BaseViewModel() {
    val ticketId = MutableLiveData<Int>()
    val ticketName = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val ticketPrice = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val pickedQuantity = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val quantities = MutableLiveData<List<String>>()
    val spinnerTitle = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val spinnerHandler = MutableLiveData<(Int) -> Unit>()

    fun bind(ticket: TicketType, onClick: (Int) -> Unit) {
        ticketId.value = ticket.ticketTypeId
        ticketName.value = ticket.ticketTypeName
        ticketPrice.value = "$"  + ticket.price
        pickedQuantity.value = "0"
        spinnerTitle.value = ""
        val temp = mutableListOf<String>()
        for (i in 0 until ticket.quota) {
            temp.add(i.toString())
        }
        quantities.value = temp.toList()
        spinnerHandler.value = { index ->
            pickedQuantity.value = quantities.value!![index]
            onClick(index)
        }
    }
}
```

TicketTypeAdapter.kt

```
class TicketTypeAdapter(val onClick: (Int) -> Unit): RecyclerView.Adapter<TicketTypeAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private var ticketList: MutableList<TicketType> = mutableListOf()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TicketTypeAdapter.ViewHolder {
        val binding: EventTicketTypeListItemBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), R.layout.event_ticket_type_list_item, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(binding, onClick)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TicketTypeAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(ticketList[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return ticketList.size
    }

    fun refreshTicketList(ticketList: List<TicketType>){
        this.ticketList.clear()
        this.ticketList.addAll(ticketList)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    class ViewHolder(private val binding: EventTicketTypeListItemBinding, val onClick: (Int) -> Unit): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){
        private val viewModel = TicketTypeViewModel()

        fun bind(ticket: TicketType){
            viewModel.bind(ticket, onClick)
            binding.ticketType = viewModel
        }
    }
}
```

In .xml

```
    <com.cityline.component.SpinnerTextView
        android:id="@+id/spinner_quantity"
        spinnerAlertTitle="@{ticketType.spinnerTitle}"
        spinnerItemHandler="@{ticketType.spinnerHandler}"
        spinnerItems="@{ticketType.quantities}"
        spinnerTitle="@{ticketType.pickedQuantity}"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_bg_bottom_line"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a call to `binding.setLifecycleOwner(this)`

> Sets the `LifecycleOwner` that should be used for observing changes of
>   `LiveData` in this binding. If a `LiveData` is in one of the binding expressions
>   and no `LifecycleOwner` is set, the `LiveData` will not be observed and updates to it
>   will not be propagated to the UI.

So either set the lifecycle owner or use `ObservableField` instead, which is better fitting.

As adapters work differently in regards of data updates, you might want to propagate changes to the adapter data set instead and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` or a similar one to update the bindings.